# Workflow request sign off - accessing if the request wasn't made by you

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-activity

i am trying to find out if there is a way, you can access the reasons for a document to be rejected on a workflow that wasn't workflow requested by you.

So for exmaple:
John Smith workflows a document for approval to another member of staff and this document gets rejected for whatever reason. John Smith they goes on leave, and Karl White is now covering for John. Without access to emails, or having to create the workflow request again, how can we access the notes from the approver?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OOB approval workflow, we could check the workflow history as shown below through clicking the result column:

[image]

[image]